# WebApplicationException message is not displayed in weblogic log properly

Tags: java, rest, jersey, weblogic

I have REST jersey service inside weblogic that throws exception:

```
throw new WebApplicationException(Response.status(Response.Status.INTERNAL_SERVER_ERROR).entity(new ApplicationException(Response.Status.INTERNAL_SERVER_ERROR.getStatusCode(),e.getMessage())).type(MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON).build());
```

exception e - contains valid error message

ApplicationException is a pojo class.

When I call the service, client displays the error message **as expected** in json format.

e.g.
{
   "status": 500,
   "message": "bla bla bla bla"
}

But in weblogic log I see:

> com.sun.jersey.spi.container.ContainerResponse logException SEVERE:
>   Mapped exception to response: 500 (Internal Server Error)
>   javax.ws.rs.WebApplicationException

SO what to do for both client and weblogic log to show the exact error message.

Comment: It is your application's reponsibility to correctly log your exceptions. WebLogic will only trace the top level error without details.

Comment: Client getting the correct error, how to make sure weblogic also logs it? is it possible?  If not , maybe I can prevent weblogic to log it completely?